# How to visualize quotient space?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm trying to understand quotient spaces.

The first example is [0,1]/~:

a~b <=> |a-b|=1

=> [0,1]/~ = {(x,y) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$|$x^2+y^2$=1}

What I get from the definition of a~b is that we "glue" together the point a = (0,0) and b = (1,0). But this definition doesn't say anything about the points "in the middle". What happens to them? How do we get a circle if we only do things to the endpoints?

Comment: "Nothing" happens to the points in the middle (though some uninterestingly large neighbourhoods of them are affected). We do not get a circle, but a space that is homeomorphic to the standard circle.

Comment: If you have a rope then - to get a chain - it is enough to do something with the endpoints, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote: that $\;|a-b|=1\;$ , with $\;a,b\in [0,1]\;$, means  that $\;0\sim1\;$ ...and that's all. This relation isn't even an equivalence one on the unit interval, so I don't get how you say, or someone told you, that you'd get the canonical unit circle...I think what is meant here is to *identify* homeomorphically the unit interval, with its end points "glued", with the canonical unit circle.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Well, simply because it isn't true that $\;a\sim a\;$ for **all** $\;a\in [0,1]\;$, so the relation isn't reflexive on  the unit interval...What the OP surely meant is to identify the end points of the unit interval by means of his definition, which then **is an equivalence relation on** $\;\{0,1\}\;$ , but not on the unit interval. This, though, could be some kind of abuse of language...

Comment: @DonAntonio you're absolutely right, sorry about that. I'll delete the post.

Answer (score 2):

1. The line segment $[0,1]$ is one dimensional, its elements have one coordinate. 
   But, yes, all what is happening here is that we glue together the two endpoints $0$ and $1$ of this segment.
2. The 'equation' you write should be read as *homeomorphic*, and it means that there are continuous functions between the two topological spaces which are inverses of each other. 
   There is a standard map you can define $\varphi:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ such that its image $\varphi([0,1])$ covers the circle once except for one point, $\varphi(0)=\varphi(1)$. 
   Specifically, this map induces a homeomorphism from $[0,1]/\sim$ to the circle.

Comment: I see. So the reason the definition of the equivalence relation exists is just to make sure that if we do want to find φ, we need to make sure that it obeys the condition φ(0)=φ(1)?

Comment: Also, just to make sure I understand this properly, if we take as an example the unit cylinder, and define (x,1)~(x',1), then we can have a map f that maps the points on the cylinder to the points of a cone (for example, if the cone is "inside" the cylinder, then one such map would be the one that sends the points "horizontally"?), and f(1,1) = f(x',1)?

Answer (score 2):

As all relations this relation induces an equivalence relation.

Note that the set of equivalence classes is $X:=\{\{x\}\mid x\in(0,1)\}\cup\{\{0,1\}\}$

Prescribe the function $\nu:[0,1]\to X$ by $x\mapsto\{x\}$ if $x\in(0,1)$ and $x\mapsto\{0,1\}$ otherwise.

Then let $X$ be equipped with quotient topology: $$\tau_X=\{U\in\wp(X)\mid\nu^{-1}(B)\text{ is open in }[0,1]\}=\{U\in\wp(X)\mid\bigcup U\text{ is open in }[0,1]\}$$

Then $\nu:[0,1]\to X$ is a quotient map.

Further prescribe $f:[0,1]\to Y:=\{\langle\cos2\pi t,\sin2\pi t\rangle\mid t\in[0,1)\}$ by $t\mapsto\langle\cos2\pi t,\sin2\pi t\rangle$.

Function $f$ is continuous, surjective and closed, hence is a quotient map.

Further $f$ and $\nu$ respect each other in the sense that: $$\nu(r)=\nu(s)\iff f(r)=f(s)$$

That implies the existence of unique  maps $h:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that $\nu=g\circ f$ and $f=h\circ\nu$.

Then $g\circ f$ and $h\circ\nu$ are both continuous, and the fact that $\nu$ and $f$ are both quotient maps allows the conclusion that $h$ and $g$ are both continuous.

Further based on uniqueness it can be shown $h\circ g=\text{id}_Y$ and $g\circ h=\text{id}_X$ so we conclude that $h$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms.

So the spaces $X=[0,1]/\sim$ and $Y$ (a circle) are homeomorphic.